# How do I delete rows in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to delete a row in database based on some condition. I tried like this

```
$fanclub        =   FanClub::find()->where(['user_id'=>$userid])->
            andwhere(['crew_member_id'=>$id])->one();
            if($fanclub)
            {
                $fanclub->delete();
            }
```

is this the right way to delete a row in database?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When working with models (`ActiveRecord`), yes, this is the right way.

You can use `$model->delete()` for deleting model. As the result, according row in related table will be deleted.

You can use `beforeDelete()` and `afterDelete()` event handlers together with this method to handle some tasks related with deletion.

Alternatives without using model:

```
\Yii::$app
    ->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->delete('users', ['id' => 1])
    ->execute();
```

or

```
use yii\db\Query;

...

(new Query)
    ->createCommand()
    ->delete('users', ['id' => 1])
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use this way

```
ProjectEmployee::deleteAll(['and',
            [ 'employee_id'=>$this->id],
            ['in', 'project_id', [2,5,7]]]
        );
```

But note that this can be used to delete single or multiple rows based on the `array` of `in`

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Probably the most straight to the point answer here.

Comment: I recommend to use this one it has better syntax and no need to foreach to delete one by one

Comment: @maryisdead The OP asked if his code is right to delete only one row, not all rows although the answer code may be valid but not safe transactionally.

Comment: @Néstor You are right. But it is not a good practice to rely only on single delete function while the query select multiple rows. You will delete one but may be the wrong one. It is alwayse more safe to make sure the query only return single row while you are executing single delete statement.

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed what? but if with a simple js you can ask to the user if is sure about to proceed. The delete is for the current activerecord (what is the question about) and in the where condition you can pass the same conditions.

Answer (score 3):

There you are getting record first, but you can do it directly

```
$fanclub = FanClub::find()
  ->where(['user_id'=>$userid])
  ->andwhere(['crew_member_id'=>$id])
  ->one()
  ->delete();
```

Comment: If `one()` returns `null`, we will get an `Call to a member function delete() on null` error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
    DELETE FROM group_members 
    WHERE group_id = '$id' 
    AND member_id = '$usr'
")->execute();
```

Comment: ...this has no explanation.

Comment: This works nice, but if I use it for UPDATE query, is it sql injection save?